Midnight Commander - User Menu - Default Selected Menu Item
I am struggling with setting the default menu item in MC.
My original goal is to have possibility to open any file or any tagged files from MC User Menu (F2) in Kate in KDE Plasma.
This settings bellow is working well.
= t r &  
+ ! t t
`       Open current file in Kate
        kate %f

= t t r &
+ t t r
`       Open tagged files in Kate
        for i in %t ; do
            kate $i
        done

But this solution didn't select the ' menu item as default. The MC menu is still selecting h menu item and I don't know why.
h menu item has this condition and body and is more deep in the menu config file
= t r &
+ ! t t
h       Strip headers from current newsarticle
        CHECK=`awk '{print $1 ; exit}' %f` 2>/dev/null
        case "$CHECK" in
            Newsgroups:|Path:)
                I=`mktemp "${MC_TMPDIR:-/tmp}/news.XXXXXX"` || exit 1
                cp %f "$I" && sed '/^'"$CHECK"' /,/^$/d' "$I" > %f
                [ "$?" = "0" ] && rm "$I"
                echo %f": header removed."
                ;;
            *)
                echo %f" is not a news article."
                ;;
        esac


